# Android SDK not found in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sdk, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, java-6

I'm beginner of C# as well as Xamarin.

I've installed Visual Studio and Xamarin but when I try to create a new project with Xamarin it shows me the following error in the output window.

```
[I:sdk]: Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
         Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
         Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]: Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
         Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55).
[I:Unknown]: Did not find Android SDK
[I:sdk]: Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
         Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
         Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]: Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
         Path contains ndk-stack.exe in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\).
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]: Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]: Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
         Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55).
[I:Unknown]: Did not find Android SDK
[I:Unknown]: Found Xamarin.Android 6.0.3
```

But I can't find the Android folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\Users\sony\AppData\Local`.

Comment: If Android SDK is not installed you will need to install it first and then set Environment Variable accordingly. Are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio ?

Comment: @sheeraj visual studio

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are sure that Android SDK is not installed, you will have to download Android SDK and install it initally. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) to Android SDK windows installer.

Once you have installed Android SDK you need to point Visual Studio to the SDK folder. Click 'Tools' in the toolbar at the top, then click 'Options'. If Android SDK Location is not detected automatically, click on 'Change' and select the location.

You may need to re-start Visual Studio after that.

[image: Options Window]

Comment: sir thanks for quick reply .but how to cheek Android SDK install or not ??I can't find the Android folder under C:\Program Files (x86) and C:\Users\sony\AppData\Local. but when i cheak on  (control panel ->visual sudio 2015 ->modify)> it's show me that android sdk already installed

Comment: @vbvs Search for "Android" in windows search bar. If Android SDK is installed in some location in the system it will appear in the search result. If you found SDK, then just move to second step. Otherwise you will need to download and install